# Error 401 Unauthorized MVC .NET WEB APP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, get

I am working with an API that wants me to send the token along with Header, specifically Content Header.

Here is my code block.

```
        string path_current_user = "me";

        var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("cookietoken");

        string cookie_with_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN="+cookie.Value+";";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookie_with_token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path_current_user);
```

I always get a 410 Unauthorized response. However, during debugging I can collect the values from the client object, and copy paste them into https://www.hurl.it, and I get the expected 200 OK response. So, I know the values that are being stored in the above code are correct. Its not a credentials issue for sure.

I have looked at almost 50 different threads on stack overflow, but none of them talk about this specification situation. Doing a GET with the Header Content set. Here is a screenshot of the HURL that works just fine.

[image]

Update 1 - Here is the API documentation for what I am trying to achieve.

> Endpoint
>
> GET me
>
> Request Route
>
> GET me
>
> Headers
>
> Content-Type: application/json Cookie: ACCESS_TOKEN="token characters
>   come here and remove the quotes"; Host: x.x

Update 2 - One of my mentors, recommended the following.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://small-project-api.herokuapp.com/me");
request.Headers.Add.("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.Headers.Add.("Cookie", cookie_with_token);
var response2 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
var responsestring = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

He is of the opinion that may be such a request, as mentioned below, simply won't work in dot net. I am all but ready to give up here.

Comment: have you maybe try to set client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Bearer ", cookie.Value);

Comment: Consider adding the cookie to the clients cookie collection before making the request.

Comment: I tried that (cookie collection) and also the other one (Bearer) previously. Did not take :( I am starting to think if the issue is with the API call itself. I am checking with the API developer.

Comment: @jay Did you resolve the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: Actually no :( I discussed with multiple experts offline as well. Eventually, we concluded that this simply does not work on dot net. For the sake of the project (which was consuming this API) we switched from dot net to iOS and it worked just fine.

So, we simply abandoned this project for the client app and chose iOS platform for the client app is the conclusion.